# How to replace an unknown amount of identical characters with a new word?

Tags: c++

What I'm trying to do is if I have a string like 
`std::string test = "2xs***gcv"` Is it possible to somehow replace all the instances of a star with a new word e.x `2xs***gcv` = `2xsWORDgcv` the issue is that the number of *'s aren't always 3 could be 5,7,2 etc but they're always beside each other.

what I have so far is

```c
std::string test = "2xs***gcv"
char *pos;
pos = strchr(result.c_str(),'*');
    while(pos!=NULL) {
        printf ("found at %d\n",pos-result.c_str()+1);
        pos=strchr(pos+1,'*');
}
```

which tells me where the *'s are located, the problem is I can't seem to figure how to isolate just the first instance of the * and that last instance.

Comment: You could use a regular expression.

Comment: @eerorika good idea, didn't even think about that, gonna try it out! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::string` has both `find` and `rfind`, so if you know your string will contain only one contiguous group of asterisks, you can find the beginning and end of them something like this:

```
auto left = test.find('*');
auto right = test.rfind('*');
```

Then you can replace that range with some new data something like this:

```
test.replace(left, right-left+1, "WORD");
```

As usual, I've omitted any error checking (and such) for simplicity/clarity.

Comment: There is also `std::string::find_first_not_of()`, too: `auto right = test.find_first_not_of("*", left+1);`